# Design idea for a project with AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I currently have a service that has two lambdas. The first lambda gets triggered by the request from the API gateway and it copies the files it gets in the request to a location in S3. And based on the type of file it gets in the request, the first lambda puts them into different folders in S3.

The second lambda gets triggered once every 10 minutes and it scans for files in the s3 bucket and fetches the files and do some operation on the file and copies it back to another folder in the S3 bucket.

The problem that I am facing is, when the second lambda gets triggered and it is processing files from a particular folder and the number of files in that folder is too many the files in the other folders don't get processed at all until all the files in the current folder is processed.

How can I efficiently solve this problem? I want to solve this only using lambdas.

One solution that I have in mind is, lets say the second lambda as a consumer. Have one primary consumer lambda, and it's only job is to check for number of files in each folders of S3, and if there are 5 folders in S3 with files in it, spawn 5 lambdas one per folder to process files in that folder. But I am not sure whether this approach is feasible or cost effective.

And one more thing to under consideration is number of folders that the primary consumer lambda need to scan wont be more than 15. At max it only has to spawn(or trigger) 15 other secondary lambdas. And number of files in each files can be as big as 20000 at any point in time and it takes around 3-4mins to process each file by the consumer lambda.

Please let me know if the approach that I have in mind works or if there are any other approaches please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I efficiently solve this problem? I want to solve this only using lambdas.

Well, that's your problem and **bad architecture**. The proper way would be to use **SQS queues** to store metadata of the S3 files to be processed. For that you would setup [S3 events notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) for your different folders, which would populate the SQS queues. The queues would trigger corresponding lambdas for further processing. You could also do it with one SQS and lambda, but this is a detail.

The point is that you should use SQS queue(s) and actually properly architect your application, rather then stick with poor design to "solve this only using lambdas". Sticking with the poor design will only lead to further issues in the future with scalability and reliability of your solution.

Comment: I did consider that option, but the problem with that is if I trigger my second lambda once for every sqs message the cost will go up drastically. The duration of each request for the second lambda is 300000ms and I get around 3 million requests every month. 
With the current architecture I trigger the second lambda with 1000 keys(files) and  all 1000 files are processed concurrently thus saving the cost.

Comment: @user3844180 You can setup batchsize for lambda, and it will fetch multiple messages from sqs. So you don't have to execute one lambda per message. You can also run your lambda on schedule as you do know, but get messages from the queue yourself.